# Jquery's Chosen plugin with Chained plugin and select box

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-chosen, chained

i'm new here

so this is the problem: I'm trying to use chosen plugin (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) with chained plugin (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) for my select boxes

but it doesn't work well. Here the link with the example

http://jsfiddle.net/hgRGm/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:**

There you have it http://jsfiddle.net/hgRGm/5/

**Medium answer:**

every time the original select change, you have to refresh chosen with `$("#original").trigger("liszt:updated");`

*You can send me a beer ;) although I prefer a good Italian cappuccino*

Comment: ahahah, thank you so much. Italian cappuccino and pizza for you :D

Answer (score 2):

Finazdeh Leiktlet Danora!  I resurrect this old question.

`"liszt:updated"` is now outdated and no longer used.

They now use `.trigger('chosen:updated');`

Just to help keep all informed of changes with Chosen since it rocks.