# What is trigger "liszt:updated" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I was following the answer here:
[Jquery's Chosen plugin with Chained plugin and select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876340/jquerys-chosen-plugin-with-chained-plugin-and-select-box)

And I found a line that I just don't follow - as I don't understand what 'liszt:updated' means - I can't find many references to this online to explain.

**Specifically in the code:**

```
 $("#budget").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

What does 'liszt:updated' in jQuery mean?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258153/ajaxchosen-plugin-will-not-work

Answer (score 24):

`liszt:updated` is just a custom event that [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) was using at the time. It is not a standard event, so you won't find anything on the web about it.

Moreover, Chosen itself doesn't use that event name any more (they're using `chosen:updated` now ), which would make it even more difficult to find any references to it.

See here: [**How do I reset a jquery-chosen select option with jQuery?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365212/how-do-i-reset-a-jquery-chosen-select-option-with-jquery/11365340#11365340).